# Нужно ли запрещать доступ к web.config по http?

Tags: php, laravel

Нужно ли запрещать доступ к чтению файла web.config через get запрос или нет?

```
location ~ web\.config$ {
    deny all;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Разумеется, доступ должен быть запрещен. Там же пароли к БД и секретные ключи к OAuth...

Но по умолчанию доступа к этому файлу и так нет, так что если ничего не сломано - то отдельно запрещать его не надо.

Comment: сейчас если зайти по url вида site.ru/web.config этот файл просто скачивается, попробую закрыть тогда через nginx

Comment: @МаксимЖелезняков, а зачем вы вообще проксируете IIS через NGINX? Если верить тестам, в Windows-окружении NGINX заметно менее эффективно раздаёт статический контент, нежели IIS. У вас просто привычка с Linux/OSX?

Comment: web.config у меня на сайте, на базе framework laravel соответственно для него я и Nginx поставил

Comment: @МаксимЖелезняков, т.е. у вас вообще не используется Microsoft IIS в качестве бекенд-сервера? Тогда смело сносите этот файл! Всё равно он ничем не используется, и в данной ситуации он является просто мусором.Его и поставляют то с laravel только как пример использования rewrite-ов в IIS.

Comment: @МаксимЖелезняков э... `laravel` - это же PHP? Откуда вообще в PHP взялся файл web.config?!

Comment: @PavelMayorov, [разработчики просто пихают как пример](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/web.config) - ничего секретного там нет - пара правил для модуля `rewrite`, сгенерированных из .htaccess при помощи [онлайн-конвертера](http://cbsa.com.br/tools/online-convert-htaccess-to-web-config.aspx) :)